# Error 405 Method Not Alowed Exception when post with AJAX with Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I just want to send two variables to my controller with an onclick event in JS, I am using laravel framework and JQuery Ajax.

My onclick call is:

```
onclick="addArt(<?php echo Session::get("ID") ?>, <?php echo $article->idArticle ?>)"
```

That goes to a function in my JS sheet:

```
function addArt(idUser, idArt){
  $.post( "addArt", { IDUser: idUser, IDArt: idArt})
  .done(function( data ) {
      location.reload();
  })
  .fail(function(e) {
      console.log(e);
  });
}
```

So my route is "addArt" and like always I have the route:

```
Route::post('addArt',"CarsController@addArt");
```

Where in my controller I just add the article to the cart with a simple insert of laravel but I get an error 405 (Method Not Alowed).

Can anyone please help me  with this?

Comment: You have double quotes inside of double quotes in your onclick method.

Comment: check whether your using `xsrf` protection in the form ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get that error because you don't pass to your post object the csrf token.

This will work:

```
onclick="addArt(<?php echo Session::get("ID") ?>, <?php echo $article->idArticle ?>, <?php echo csrf_token(); ?>)"
```

and on your function you need to pass the _token value

```
function addArt(idUser, idArt, token){
  $.post( "addArt", { IDUser: idUser, IDArt: idArt, _token: token})
  .done(function( data ) {
      location.reload();
  })
  .fail(function(e) {
      console.log(e);
  });
}
```

Comment: Itryed with that but I catch this: Uncaught ReferenceError: SQz357JLjhShufbaxKzRx4QlKUIgQ6o1xZ3b0Hjq is not defined

Comment: My error was in the path of the route just that but thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Laravel's Blade Templating, you can change a bit and have it work still:

```
onclick="addArt('{{Session::get("ID")}}', '{{$article->idArticle}}')"
// " " does work inside the {{ }} tags if using Blade.
```

If you inspect the element now, it should look like this:

```
onclick="addArt('session', 'article')"
```

Hope that helps!